# Spring data , как написать запрос?

Tags: java, запрос, spring-data, spring-jpa

Есть сущности :

**Train:**

```
package dev5.lavishek.trains.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

@Table
@Entity
public class Train extends BaseEntity {

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<DayOfWeek> availableDay = new ArrayList<>();
  @OneToMany
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  private List<Ride> rides = new ArrayList<>();
  @ManyToMany
  private List<RailwayCarriage> carriages = new ArrayList<>();

  public Train() {
  }

  public Train(List<DayOfWeek> availableDay, List<Ride> rides,
      List<RailwayCarriage> carriages) {
    this.availableDay = availableDay;
    this.rides = rides;
    this.carriages = carriages;
  }



  public List<DayOfWeek> getAvailableDay() {
    return availableDay;
  }

  public void setAvailableDay(List<DayOfWeek> availableDay) {
    this.availableDay = availableDay;
  }

  public List<RailwayCarriage> getCarriages() {
    return carriages;
  }

  public void setCarriages(List<RailwayCarriage> carriages) {
    this.carriages = carriages;
  }

  public List<Ride> getRides() {
    return rides;
  }

  public void setRides(List<Ride> rides) {
    this.rides = rides;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "availableDay=" + availableDay +
        " rides=" + rides +
        ", carriages=" + carriages;
  }
}
```

**DayOfWeek :**

```
package dev5.lavishek.trains.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class DayOfWeek extends BaseEntity {

  @Column
  private java.time.DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "availableDay")
  private List<Train> trains = new ArrayList<>();

  public DayOfWeek() {
  }

  public DayOfWeek(java.time.DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
  }

  public java.time.DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
    return dayOfWeek;
  }

  public void setDayOfWeek(java.time.DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
  }

  public List<Train> getTrains() {
    return trains;
  }

  public void setTrains(List<Train> trains) {
    this.trains = trains;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return
        super.toString() + "dayOfWeek=" + dayOfWeek;
  }
}
```

**Ride:**

```
package dev5.lavishek.trains.entity;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class Ride extends BaseEntity {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Schedule schedule;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Station stationFrom;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Station stationTo;

  public Ride(Schedule schedule, Station stationFrom, Station stationTo) {
    this.schedule = schedule;
    this.stationFrom = stationFrom;
    this.stationTo = stationTo;
  }

  public Ride() {

  }

  public Ride(Integer id, Schedule schedule, Station stationFrom,
      Station stationTo) {
    super(id);
    this.schedule = schedule;
    this.stationFrom = stationFrom;
    this.stationTo = stationTo;
  }

  public Ride(Integer id) {
    super(id);
  }

  public Schedule getSchedule() {
    return schedule;
  }

  public void setSchedule(Schedule schedule) {
    this.schedule = schedule;
  }

  public Station getStationFrom() {
    return stationFrom;
  }

  public void setStationFrom(Station stationFrom) {
    this.stationFrom = stationFrom;
  }

  public Station getStationTo() {
    return stationTo;
  }

  public void setStationTo(Station stationTo) {
    this.stationTo = stationTo;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "schedule=" + schedule +
        ", stationFrom=" + stationFrom +
        ", stationTo=" + stationTo;
  }
}
```

Необходимо написать запрос (`@Query`) для **Train** :

```
  @Query()
  List<Train> getTrainByAvailableDayAndStations(@Param("AvailableDay") DayOfWeek day,
      @Param("FromSt") Station from,
      @Param("ToSt") Station to);
```

Надо выбрать все поезда у которых есть `@Param("AvailableDay")` и в списке `train.rides` есть `ride` у которого `stationFrom` совпадает с `@Param("FromSt")` , и 
`ride` у которого `stationTo` совпадает с `@Param("ToSt")`, при чем это могут быть разные `ride` из списка `train.rides` .

Еще если это реально желательно проверить , что индекс `ride` который содержит `FromSt` меньше индекса `ride` , который содержит `ToSt` в списке `train.ride`

**В данный момент реализовал так :**

```
@Query(value = "
SELECT train FROM 
Train train INNER JOIN train.rides ride INNER JOIN train.availableDay day 
WHERE (day.dayOfWeek=:AvailableDay) AND
        (ride.stationFrom=:FromSt OR ride.stationTo=:ToSt) 
GROUP BY train.id)
")
```

Но проблема в том ,что здесь `Ride` это одна и та же поездка, а нужно у разных , + мне почему то возвращает несколько **train** с одинаковым **id**, поэтому использую костыль ( `GROUP By` ).

Comment: больше похоже на заказ, чем на вопрос =)

Comment: Немного поправил свой вопрос ,чтобы не казалось ,что я хочу всё с нуля и готовенькое =) Да и какой это заказ , один sql ( хз как называется запрос в spring data ) запрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если вам нужно разные поездки, так и пишите разные поездки, как-то так (не проверял, но суть должны быть понятна)

```
@Query(value = "
SELECT train FROM 
Train train INNER JOIN train.rides ride1 INNER JOIN train.rides ride2
    INNER JOIN train.availableDay day 

WHERE (day.dayOfWeek=:AvailableDay) AND
        (ride1.stationFrom=:FromSt OR ride2.stationTo=:ToSt) 

GROUP BY train.id)
")
```

А то что у вас несколько раз возвращается **train** это нормально, так как сущностей **ride** у **train** много он для каждой вернет **train** (sql же не в курсе что вам нужны только уникальные id). Можете попробовать так

```
@Query(value = "
SELECT DISTINCT train FROM 
Train train INNER JOIN train.rides ride1 INNER JOIN train.rides ride2
    INNER JOIN train.availableDay day 

WHERE (day.dayOfWeek=:AvailableDay) AND
        (ride1.stationFrom=:FromSt OR ride2.stationTo=:ToSt) 

)
")
```

Но я не уверен, поддерживается ли `DISTINCT` всегда и везде (вроде он в стандарте SQL, но всякое бывает).

Comment: Спасибо большое ,понял